Automating Azure AD App Registration Using Bicep Script
I am looking to automate the process of Azure AD App Registration using Bicep scripts. Specifically, I want to:
Create Azure AD applications automatically during deployment.
Assign appropriate API permissions to these applications.
Set up authentication configurations for the applications.
Use Managed Identity for authentication within the Bicep deployment script.
Could you provide guidance or an example of how to structure a Bicep script to automate this process? What are the necessary resources, role assignments, and permissions needed for this automation?

You could probably have a look at the documentation to start with: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/templates/

Did you try any script?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1292111/app-service-authentication-aad-automatically-creat

Now there is, in Preview:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/identity/bicep-templates-for-microsoft-graph-resources/
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-bicep-types/tree/main/quickstart-templates
Quite a bit of documentation missing, but it's a matter of time now.

